# Putting robots.txt, favicon and other files to another directory

Tags: html, url, seo, robots.txt, favicon

I have my own directory for static files and that's why I want to move my favicon, robots.txt, sitemap and other files of the same sort to it. Therefore, these files will be accessible not as `my_website.com/robots.txt`, `my_website.com/favicon.ico`, but `my_website.com/my_files_path/robots.txt`, `my_website.com/my_files_path/favicon.ico`

I wonder, won't this hurt my website in terms of SEO? Are there other drawbacks? Is it better to put these files in the root directory?

Comment: Not sure about the robots.txt. But you are able to specify the directory for the favicon in the .htaccess, though for simplicity I would keep them where they belong.

Answer (score 3):

Web robots will look for the robots.txt in your root directory. So it's a good idea to place it there. On [this page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en) Google says:

> In order to make a robots.txt file, you need access to the root of your domain.

Most browsers will look for a favicon.ico in your root aswell. You can specify a different path to your icon with the `<link>` element. However, remember that all files on your site is not HTML. If a user views an image, PDF or similar then the `<link>` element will not work. In such cases, the browser will likely fall back on the file in the root folder.